# Disable `<a>` link inside <ul> issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I do have a block of HTML code for nested list as below:

```
<ul>       
  <li class="level_1">
    <a href="level1.html">Insulated And Extruded</a>
    <ul class="level_2">
      <li><a href="">TE77</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TE78</a></li>
      <li><a href="">T77</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TS77</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level_1"><a href="">Grille Type Rolling</a></li>
  <li class="level_1"><a href="">PVC High Speed Doors</a></li>
  <li class="level_1"><a href="">Swinging doors</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using this what I need to do is, I want to check `li.level_1` has a `<ul>`, if so then I need to disable `<a>` link link which is directly inside `li.level_1`.

This is how I tried it in jquery, but its removing all `a` from the list.

```
if($('ul li').has('ul').length) {
  $('ul li > a').removeAttr('href'); 
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix that issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if `li` has `ul` and disable `a` like this.

```js
$('.level_1:has(ul) > a').removeAttr('href')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>       
  <li class="level_1">
    <a href="level1.html">Insulated And Extruded</a>
    <ul class="level_2">
      <li><a href="">TE77</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TE78</a></li>
      <li><a href="">T77</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TS77</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level_1"><a href="">Grille Type Rolling</a></li>
  <li class="level_1"><a href="">PVC High Speed Doors</a></li>
  <li class="level_1"><a href="">Swinging doors</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set an event listener like this:

Set an id to the top level ul element:

```
<ul id="top_level_ul">
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '#top_level_ul > li > a', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE (pointer-events)**

You can also set `pointer-events:none` to prevent any interaction:

```
$('#top_level_ul > li > a').each(function() {
   $(this.addClass('noPointer'));
});
```

CSS

```
.noPointer {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start your "search" for links from `$('ul li')`

```
var $node = $('ul li');
if($node.has('ul').length) {
  $node.find('ul li > a').removeAttr('href'); 
}
```

See following example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>       
  <li class="level_1">
    <a href="level1.html">Insulated And Extruded</a>
    <ul class="level_2">
      <li><a href="">TE77</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TE78</a></li>
      <li><a href="">T77</a></li>
      <li><a href="">TS77</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level_1"><a href="">Grille Type Rolling</a></li>
  <li class="level_1"><a href="">PVC High Speed Doors</a></li>
  <li class="level_1"><a href="">Swinging doors</a></li>
</ul> 
  <script>
    var $node = $('ul li');
    if($node.has('ul').length) {
      $node.find('ul li > a').removeAttr('href'); 
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps you. Bye.

Comment: will affect all the `<a>` in sub `<ul>` also

Comment: Oh, I understood now... let me check.

Comment: put an href in the nested links and you will see. Your whole approach needs re-thinking. The `if()` is not filtering specific matches either

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://jsbin.com/tomifi/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.level_2').siblings('a').remove();
});
```

UPD

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.level_2').siblings('a').css('pointer-events','none');
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.level_2').siblings('a').attr('onclick','return false');
});
```

Comment: actually simplest approach ... remove() is not correct though

Comment: "$('.level_2').siblings('a')..." as a way to get the problematic link.

Comment: yes...understood, but OP doesn't want to remove the whole element, just disable it

Comment: Ok! $('.level_2').siblings('a').css('pointer-events', 'none');